# Split a string to a specific format in c#?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string of format like `({a,b,c,d},{(a,b),(b,c),(a,c),(c,d)})`. I want to split and store it in 2 arrays ,1 will contain `a,b,c,d` and other will store `ab,bc,ac,cd`.

I am doing it in a complete vague way.

```
string str = "({a,b,c,d},{(a,b),(b,c),(a,c),(c,d)})";
var node = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2).Replace("},{", "}|{").Split('|')[0].Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Split(',');  
var path = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2).Replace("},{", "}|{").Split('|')[1].Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").
            Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("),", "|").Replace(",", "").Split('|');
```

Please suggest me to do it in a better way.

**EDIT**

The first part of the string will contain the nodes like `{n1,n2,n3...n}` and the Second part will contain the paths between the nodes `{(n1,n2),(n2,n3),...}`

Comment: is that a `string`? or `string[]`

Comment: Your first line of code isn't valid code.

Comment: Sorry I missed the quotes

Comment: @LONG it's a string

Comment: Replacing ")" with "" before replacing ")," with "|" isn't going to work.  You'd need to replace the ")," first.

Comment: Is there any way to convert that string to string array?

Comment: if you tell us which parts of the string may vary then someone could come up with better solution

Comment: A Regex should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions.

```
string str = "({a,b,c,d},{(a,b),(b,c),(a,c),(c,d)})";
string group1 = new Regex(@"\{([a-z],?)*\}").Match(str).Value;
string group2 = new Regex(@"(\(([a-z],?)*\),?)+").Match(str).Value;
string[] arr1 = group1.Substring(1, group1.Length-2).Split(',');
string[] arr2 = group2.Split(new[] { "),(" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"[^a-z]+", String.Empty)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string str = "({a,b,c,d},{(a,b),(b,c),(a,c),(c,d)})";
            str = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2)
                .Replace("},{", "}|{").Replace("{", "").Replace("}","")
                .Replace("),(", ";").Replace("(", "")
                .Replace(")", "").Replace(",", "");
            string[] arrStr = str.Split('|');

            string[] s1 = arrStr[0].Split(',');
            string[] s2 = arrStr[1].Split(';');
```

Comment: First array contains only one element "abcd". Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

With this method, you can use any number of arrays:

```
private static List<List<string>> ConvertStringToListList(string str){

    List<List<string>> bufferListList = new List<List<string>>();

    do{ 
        var startArrayIndex = str.IndexOf("{")+1;
        var endArrayIndex = str.IndexOf("}")+1;

        var array = str.Substring(startArrayIndex, endArrayIndex-startArrayIndex);

        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

        if(array.Contains("(")){

            do{
                var startArrayIndex2 = array.IndexOf("(")+1;
                var endArrayIndex2 = array.IndexOf(")")+1;

                var array2 = array.Substring(startArrayIndex2, endArrayIndex2-startArrayIndex2);

                stringList.Add(array2.Replace(",","").Replace(")",""));

                array = array.Substring(endArrayIndex2, array.Length - endArrayIndex2);

            }while(array.Contains("("));

        }else{
            array = array.Replace("}","");

            foreach(var strings in array.Split(',')){

            stringList.Add(strings);

            }
        }

        bufferListList.Add(stringList);

        str = str.Substring(endArrayIndex, str.Length - endArrayIndex);

    }while(str.Contains("{"));  

    return bufferListList;

}
```

The return value is a list of your arrays/lists.

You can play with this method here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AVggNf

---

Examples:

Input: `"({a,b,c,d},{(a,b),(b,c),(a,c),(c,d)})"`

Outout:

- List 1: a
- List 1: b
- List 1: c
- List 1: d
- List 2: ab
- List 2: bc
- List 2: ac
- List 2: cd

Input: `"({(a,b)},{(a,c),(c,d)}, {a,b})"`

Outout:

- List 1: ab
- List 2: ac
- List 2: cd
- List 3: a
- List 3: b